# Como faço para conectar um banco de dados numa aplicação JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

Tenho uma aplicação `Java` e um banco de dados `MySQL` conectado nesta aplicação em minha máquina. A aplicação será distribuída para outras máquina da mesma rede, mas não consigo fazer a conexão do `banco de dados` para outras máquinas.
A conexão funciona certinho localmente, porém, quando tento rodar a aplicação em outra máquina da mesma rede, a conexão falha. No MySQL consigo acessar o banco de dados remotamente. Esse é o código da conexão na aplicação `Java` (estou usando `NetBeans`).

```
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://NOMEDOSERVER:3306/DB";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, "root", "SENHA");
```

Answer (score 1):

A única coisa de errada no seu código é a chamada desnecessária a `newInstance()` (basta usar `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` apenas). Fora isso não há nada de errado no seu código.

Tem certeza que as demais máquinas conseguem enxergar o servidor de banco de dados com o nome dado? Para testar isso use o ping. Além disso, certifique-se de que não haja restrições devido a firewalls, ACLs e roteamento de rede.

Comment: Sim, há resposta com o ping, mas não sei se o problema é que estou usando minha máquina como servidor do banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sei o quão familiarizado você está com o JDBC mas essa é uma classe que faz uma conexão com o banco de dados mysql, que é o seu caso. Lembre-se que você precisa de uma jar de conexão também...de novo não sei qual o problema que você está passando por isso desenvolva-o.

***Classe FabricaDeConexao:***

> ```
> import java.sql.Connection;
> import java.sql.DriverManager;
> import java.sql.SQLException;
>
> public class FabricaDeConexao {
>   private static final String user = "root";
>   private static final String password = "SENHA";
>   private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB";
>   private static Connection con = null;
>
>   public static Connection getConexao() {
>
>       try {
>
>           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
>           con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
>           return con;
>
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
>           return null;
>       }
>   }
>
>   public static void fechar() throws SQLException {
>       if (con != null) {
>           con.close();
>
>       }
>   }
>
> }
> ```

***Classe de teste:***

> ```
> import java.sql.Connection;
> import java.sql.SQLException;
>
>
> public class TestaConexao {
>   public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
>       Connection conexao = new FabricaDeConexao().getConexao();
>       System.out.println("Conexão aberta!");
>       conexao.close();
>       
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: A conexão com o banco de dados funciona corretamente na minha máquina. A aplicação roda normal na minha máquina, onde está o banco de dados também. Porém, quando eu tento acessar a aplicação em outra máquina da mesma rede, o banco não conecta. Pelo MySQL consigo acessar o banco de dados remotamente.

Comment: @Simone Isole o problema tentando acessar, primeiramente, a tela inicial do tomcat remoto, ou seja, tente carregar a página root do tomcat `http://<ip>:8080/`.
Só depois tente incluir o banco de dados conforme as dicas anteriores.